# Display all Categories

Tags: categories

I use this to display all categories:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'child_of'            => 0,
    'current_category'    => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 1,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 1,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
    'separator'           => ' ',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => '',
    'style'               => 'h3',
    'taxonomy'            => 'category',
    'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
); 

var_dump( wp_list_categories($args) );  ?>
```

But it also gives me back the word "NULL".

[image]

How can I remove the "NULL"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It seems the NULL came trough the `$args`.

```
            <?php wp_list_categories( array(
   'child_of'            => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 1,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 0,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => 1,
    'hierarchical'        => 0,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'title',
    'separator'           => ' ',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => 'A – Z | ',
    'style'               => 0,
    'taxonomy'            => 'category',
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1
    ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) has an argument `echo` with you have set to 1 (true). When if it is set to true, instead of returning the value, the function will output the content. Because nothing was returned the `var_dump` displays null.

Change the `echo` to false in your arguments array to have the value returned.

Comment: Thank you for your Help!

Sadly it wasn't it.

NULL disappears, therefor string(244) " appears.